# How can I match product ID attribute from my xml and then put the product elements into an array

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have xml structured like below and I want to loop over the xml with php and match the product id attribute. If I get a match I want to add the product elements to an array and return them from a function.

```
<Includes>
    <Products>
        <Product id="11348613">
             <name>Product A</name>
             <description>Product A's description</description>
             <image>http://www.domain.com/images/productA.jpg</image>
         </Product>
        <Product id="11348614">
             <name>Product B</name>
             <description>Product B's description</description>
             <image>http://www.domain.com/images/productB.jpg</image>
         </Product>
    </Products>
</Includes>
```

The code I have so far is as follows how this isn't quite working as I don't think I understand how to match the attribute and then return the elements. Can you point out where I am going wrong?

```
function lookupSkuFromProdId($ProductId) {
    $reviewsXML = simplexml_load_file('reviews.xml');
    foreach ($reviewsXML->Includes->Products->attributes() as $sku) {
        if ($sku == $ProductId) {   
            $skuData = array();
            $skuData[name] = $sku->name;
            $skuData[description] = $sku->description;
            $skuData[image] = $sku->image;    
        }
    return $skuData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues fixed, including... missing end brace, looping through `<Product>` elements instead of attributes, then checking attribute value within the loop and breaking when a match is found...

```
function lookupSkuFromProdId($ProductId) {
    $reviewsXML = simplexml_load_file('reviews.xml');
    foreach ($reviewsXML->Products->Product as $sku) {
        if ($sku['id'] == $ProductId) {  
            $skuData = array();
            $skuData['name'] = (string)$sku->name;
            $skuData['description'] = (string)$sku->description;
            $skuData['image'] = (string)$sku->image;
            break;    
        }
    }
    return $skuData;
}
```

See demo of similar code at [codepad.viper-7.com/8ONLaK](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8ONLaK)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [code snippet](http://codepad.org/0GygXMp2) to get what you're looking for using XPath to match the product using it's ID.

> Keep in mind some subtle changes in my code:
>
> 1. Your XML wasn't valid as it had an extra `</Product>` closing tag right before the `</Products>` closing tag;
> 2. Renamed your `$ProductId` variable to `$productId` for CamelCase consistency;
> 3. Added the SimpleXMLElement variable as a 2nd argument to the `lookupSkuFromProdId` function, but you can load it from the file as you had.

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<Includes>
    <Products>
        <Product id="11348613">
            <name>Product A</name>
            <description>Product A's description</description>
            <image>http://www.domain.com/images/productA.jpg</image>
        </Product>
        <Product id="11348614">
            <name>Product B</name>
            <description>Product B's description</description>
            <image>http://www.domain.com/images/productB.jpg</image>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</Includes>
XML;

$reviewsXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$productId  = 11348613;

function lookupSkuFromProdId($productId, $reviewsXML) {
    $skuData = array();

    // Loading it from a PHP variable for this example only
    // Just uncomment this and load it as before
    // $reviewsXML = simplexml_load_file('reviews.xml');

    $sku = $reviewsXML->xpath("//Product[@id = '{$productId}']");

    if (!empty($sku)) {
        $skuData[name]        = (string) $sku[0]->name;
        $skuData[description] = (string) $sku[0]->description;
        $skuData[image]       = (string) $sku[0]->image;
    }

    return $skuData;
}

$skuData = lookupSkuFromProdId($productId, $reviewsXML);
print_r($skuData);
```

#### Ouput:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Product A
    [description] => Product A's description
    [image] => http://www.domain.com/images/productA.jpg
)
```

Comment: I get this error when I uncomment the simplexml_load_file line. Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object... Any idea? – Ben Paton 22 secs ago

Comment: Your `simplexml_load_file` call must be failing and returning `FALSE`. Are you sure the path to the file is correct?

Answer (score 0):

i see several problems with your approach, you are not looping through the xml tree correctly, you need to cast the XML object to a string in order to save its value to the array, and you were missing a bracket and quotes around the array indexes. i've modified your code, try this:

```
function lookupSkuFromProdId($ProductId) {
    $reviewsXML = simplexml_load_file('reviews.xml');
    $skuData = array();
    foreach($reviewsXML->Products[0]->Product as $sku) {
        if ($sku['id'] == $ProductId){
            $skuData['name'] = (string)$sku->name;
            $skuData['description'] = (string)$sku->description;
            $skuData['image'] = (string)$sku->image;    
        }
    }
    return $skuData;
}
```

hope it helps!